# PUT XMLHttpRequest returns an empty at console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to send a `PUT` request through `XMLHttpRequest` but it return an empty using JS for the front end and nodejs for the backend. while in the network section in the dev tools, it shows that `PUT` is ok . I have been dealing with this for over 10 days, every iota of support will be highly appreciated. I really need this as I don't know what to do next. It's driving me nuts.

Below is my html

```
<body>
    <form action="location.js" id="myLocation" method="PUT">
        <br>
        <div>
            <label> location </label>
            <input id="location" type="text" name="location" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <button type=submit>submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="locate">

    </div>

    <a href="login.html"> GO TO LOGIN </a>

    <script src="location.js"> </script>
    <script src=""> </script>
</body>
```

Next is the JS for `XMLHttpRequest`

```
var form = document.getElementById('myLocation');
var display = document.getElementById('locate');

form.addEventListener('submit', sendData);

function sendData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var location = document.getElementById('location').value;
    var params = JSON.stringify({
        "location": location
    });

    var val = params;

    const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.onload = function () { 
        var out1 = this.responseText;
        
        display.innerHTML = out1;

        console.log(out1);
    };
    
    XHR.open('PUT', 'http://localhost:5000/parcel/:id/location', true);
    XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    XHR.setRequestHeader('Method', 'PUT');
  
    XHR.send(val);
}
```

Below is the API router for the PUT request:

```
router.put('/:id/location', async (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, application/json;charset=utf-8");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Method", "PUT");

    let parcels

    try {
        const {_id} = req.params.id;
        const {location} = req.body.location;

        parcels = await parcel.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, location);
        
        res.send(parcels);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);

        if (parcels == null) {
            res.send('error nul')
        } else{
            res.send('unsuccesful')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: A `PUT` request is not supposed to return any content. In order to verify a `PUT` request was successful you would need to check the HTTP status - [source](https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/#put)

Comment: Wao, I am very grateful for this information. I Checked through the HTTP status and it indicate 200 for OK on PUT,  but the old value does not change to a new value.

Answer (score 0):

```
XHR.open('PUT', 'http://localhost:5000/parcel/:id/location', true);
```

I think that `:id` is not right here.

Edit:

`:id` is a "route parameter". The listener can use it to cover a range of routes.

So if your API gets a `GET request` on `/parcel/0001/location` or `/parcel/asd/location` then the `/parcel/:id/location` handler can respond to all of them, and you can read the `id` from `req.params.id`.

You can only use this feature if you already know `:id` on the client side, and you can build it into the route e.g: `"http://localhost:5000/parcel/"+id+"/location"`.

Comment: I am also thinking the same but i am new to the stack. can you please explain how best i can get it done ?

Comment: `:id` is a "route parameter".

The listener can use it to cover a range of routes.

So if your API gets a `GET request` on `/parcel/0001/location` or `/parcel/asd/location` then the `/parcel/:id/location` handler can respond to all of them, and you can read the `id` from `req.params.id`.

You can only use this feature if you already know `:id` on the client side, and you can build it into the route e.g: `"http://localhost:5000/parcel/"+id+"/location"`.

Comment: Wao, thanks so much for this information. After I followed that step, it's successful while checking through the devtool on Chrome but the data I want to update did not change from old value. I'm a step ahead now and still hoping for better functionality.

Comment: Is there a reason for using `XMLHttpRequest`? `XML` and `JSON` are different formats. I usually use a package called `axios` for Http requests.

Comment: Try to stringify the body before sending: `XHR.send(JSON.stringify(val));`

Comment: I am using xmlhttprequest to send data to backend, the fronted is on different server while backend is also on different server. I tried to stringify the send as you said but I got a JSON error. Very grateful for you consistence support.

Comment: On the server side, in the error handling, change `res.send(...)` to `res.status(400).send(...)`. 400 will be the HTTP status code of the answer from the server, so you can see if something went wrong there. Different numbers mean different errors, I'd suggest googleing `HTTP error codes`. Just to be on the safe side, could you console log the `id` and the `location ` before the `findByIdAndUpdate`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239040/discussion-between-gabriel-and-afolabi-toheeb).